# pymongo commands not recognized

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I can't issue commands from pymongo to mongodb databases. I managed up to now to issue update commands and they worked, but not things like find and insert

```
import pymongo
import os
import sys
from pymongo import MongoClient

if __name__=='__main__':
    client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
    db=client['lista']
    collection=db['AllCards']
    current_ops=db.current_op(True)
    db.runCommand({find:{"name":"David"}})
```

This code keeps giving me the error message `"find" not defined.`
I need the result of the query to be shown on the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `runCommand()` method directly, use [`find()`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find):

```
cursor = collection.find({"name":"David"})
for doc in cursor:
    print(doc)
```

> how could i use mongodb operators in there? like $in, etc?

Example using `$in` operator:

```
collection.find({"name": {"$in": ["David", "John"]}})
```

Comment: how could i use mongodb operators in there? like $in, etc?
i tried this
cursor = collection.find({"name":{$in:"David"}}) but it didnt work